# Topbar icons not showing in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, top-bar

In Firefox, the topbar icons aren't showing (it's just black there). I looked at the CSS, and the new style is

```
background-image: url('../img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=2d10b452229b'),none;
```

Changing it to

```
background-image: url('../img/share-sprite-new.png?v=2d10b452229b');
```

worked, but with the SVG, it wouldn't load.

Comment: I've heard another report of this in Chrome. I haven't been able to reproduce.

Comment: This seems to be happening with a specific list subscription using adblock plus.

Comment: @Oded: Confirmed. I have Chrome 38.0.2125.111 on Windows 8, and the topbar images disappeared yesterday. I disabled Adblock Plus and now they're back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Topbar Blocked by AdBlock Plus Using the Fanboy Annoyances List

I was having the same problem, and @Oded's comments helped me track it down. The problem is that https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=2d10b452229b triggers on `/share-sprite-` from the [Fanboy Annoyances List](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/) in AdBlock Plus.

I've outlined two ways to fix this, but there are certainly others. Your mileage may vary.

#### Disable Filter

To fix it, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and click the red x to disable that filter altogether. This applies to all sites, not just StackExchange.

#### Create Filter Exception

Alternatively, you can open the Adblock Plus preferences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and create a [custom filter](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters) with finer-grained permissions that apply just to the StackExchange network and its CDN. For example:

```
@@/(stack(exchange|overflow)|sstatic).*sprite/
```

There may be a more efficient way to specify the exception, as AdBlock Plus will mark this exception rule with a snail, but it will certainly get the job done. Your mileage with custom filters and regular expressions will certainly vary.

Comment: It worked on Meta, but not elsewhere. I thing the general principle is sound (i.e. Adblock), but why isn't it working elsewhere?

Comment: @cpast Some StackExchange assets use cdn.sstatic.com as their CDN, so the filter exception might not trigger. `@@/(stack(exchange|overflow)|sstatic).*sprite/` will work better across more SE sites, but it may still miss assets on some sites. YMMV.